# insert variable date on php query with getJson

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, getjson

I got this query made on PHP that must change accordding different values.

I need to input these variables on my html page, i named one of this values as shiftdate, but probably I will have to put more variables via json on the query.

the problem is that my query doesn´t read the var

i Have this right Now

```html
<?php 

function getArraySQL(){
$dsn = "prueba";
$connect = odbc_connect( $dsn, '', '' );
$shiftdate = $_GET["shiftdate"];  //one of the variables that i need to input on my query
$query = "  SELECT hist_statusevents.reason, Sum(hist_statusevents.duration/3600) AS 'Duracion'
FROM hist_statusevents, hist_eqmtlist, hist_exproot
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex  AND hist_exproot.ddmmyy =$shiftdate
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.reason
ORDER BY Duracion DESC";

if(!$rs = odbc_exec($connect, $query)) die();

$rawdata = array();

$i=0;

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
{
$rawdata[$i] = $row;
$i++;
}
odbc_close( $connect );
return $rawdata;
}
$myarray = getArraySQL();
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

the value that i want to get into the query is in this html section:

```
                <section class="post col-md-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Date on dd-mm-yy" id="shiftdate">

                </section>
```

Passed trough this json (whitout the ,{shiftdate: "shiftdate"},it works perfectly) but if I add it, it doesnt work :

$(document)    .ready (function(){
                    $.getJSON('dbquery_plus_shiftdate.php',{shiftdate: "shiftdate"}, function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key,val){
                        $('ul').append(''+val.reason+'-'+val.Duracion+'');
                        });
                    });
                 });

on the other side, with the

$shiftdate = $_GET["shiftdate"];  //one of the variables that i need to input on my query

the php page give me this error:

Notice: Undefined index: shiftdate in C:\xampp\htdocs\byp1\dbquery_plus_shiftdate.php on line 5

Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\byp1\dbquery_plus_shiftdate.php on line 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to achieve becouse i don't understand your question.
You want to populate your html with data from query, or want to get Json by data you puted into inputs.

Comment: Sorry, i need to execute the query on the php and show the results on my html page, but I need to insert some parameters on the query, and  this paraemters must be inserted by the client in this case, te date for the query.

Comment: at this moment if I leave the php withou insert the var shifdate i works perfectly, but i need to inser shifdate as a variable of the query

Comment: Ok,  so this should do the trick
    var shiftdate = $('#shiftdate').val();
    $.getJSON('dbquery_plus_shiftdate.php',{shiftdate: shiftdate} ...

previously you was just passing string "shiftdate" to php function.

Comment: Thath part should be on the HTML? the php must remain as is?

Comment: I leave it like this:

<script>
     $(document) .ready (function(){
      shiftdate = $('#shiftdate').val()
      $.getJSON('dbquery_plus_shiftdate.php',{shiftdate: shiftdate}, function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(key,val){
       $('ul').append('<li Reason="'+val.reason+'">'+val.reason+'-'+val.Duracion+'</li>');
       });
      });
     });
     </script>

Comment: I need to add a form style to send te info to the php?